# SQL: Get data in range

Tags: sql, sqlite

**table1:**

```
id  chapter     sentence    text
1   1             1     This is line1
2   1             2     This is line2   
3   1             3     This is line3
4   1             4     This is line4
5   2             1     This is line1
6   2             2     This is line2   
7   2             3     This is line3
8   2             4     This is line4
9   2             5     This is line5
10  2             6     This is line6
11  2             7     This is line7
12  3             1     This is line1
13  3             2     This is line2
14  3             3     This is line3
15  3             4     This is line4
16  3             5     This is line5
```

I am trying to get data in range. I have tried some queries but do not get expected results.

```
GetData(beginingChapter, endingChapter, beginingSentence, endingSentence)
GetData(1, 3, 3, 4)
```

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE (chapter=1 AND sentence>=2) OR (chapter=3 AND sentence>= 1 AND sentence<= 4);
```

**Excepted results:**

```
3   1       3       This is line3
4   1       4       This is line4
5   2       1       This is line1
6   2       2       This is line2   
7   2       3       This is line3
8   2       4       This is line4
9   2       5       This is line5
10  2       6       This is line6
11  2       7       This is line7
12  3       1       This is line1
13  3       2       This is line2
14  3       3       This is line3
15  3       4       This is line4
```

Any suggestions? How to achieve expected results?

Comment: Why do you expect that? What is for example with the second record(ID=2), it's chapter is 1 and sentence is 2, so it maches your filter(`chapter=1 AND sentence>=2`). Why do you not expect to see it? You also expect `2, 6 ` even if you've excluded chapter 2 completly.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: The database is created in SQLite.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I have not excluded any chapter. I wanted to get results in range. In the method call: beginingChapter, endingChapter explains the story.

Comment: Next time you should consider to clarify your requirement better. A few explanatory words simplify the matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to structure the query to have one condition for all pages that match the lower limit and one for the upper limit and simply AND them together;

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE (( chapter = 1 AND sentence >= 3 ) OR chapter > 1)
  AND (( chapter = 3 AND sentence <= 4 ) OR chapter < 3)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fa846/1).

Answer (score 0):

According to:

```
GetData(beginingChapter, endingChapter, beginingSentence, endingSentence)
GetData(1, 3, 3, 4)
```

I'd do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE 
chapter BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
AND 
sentence BETWEEN 3 AND 4
```

but I don't understand your expected results

Answer (score 0):

your expected result is not clear,

In my understanding please try below query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (chapter Between 1 AND 3) AND (sentence Between 3 AND 4);
```